# Java: Dispose ActionEvent from different JFrame

Tags: java, swing, dispose

I want one JFrame to have a method like this:

```
private void someEvent(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

    //initialize another JFrame
    //set the new JFrame to be visible
    //set this JFrame to be disabled

}
```

Which is possible, but I also want the main JFrame to perform something when the newly created JFrame is disposed. I don't want to pass in the main JFrame to the new JFrame however. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, use [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) to switch between the two desired content panes. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513).

Answer (score 4):

Don't have one JFrame create and display another JFrame. Instead the second window should be a JDialog, either modal if you want the first window frozen until the second has been dealt with or non-modal if otherwise.  If modal then the first window's code will resume once the JDialog has been disposed of, and the code flow will start right after the `setVisible(true)` call on the dialog. If non-Modal, you'll likely want to add a WindowListener to the dialog.

For example, please check out my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855227/wait-for-jdialog-to-close/7855459#7855459), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914013/one-jframe-opening-another/4914063#4914063), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523471/action-listener-to-jdialog-for-clicked-button/8524302#8524302).